# jest with enzyme - how to test a component from other library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Let's say I have a `<AccordionItem>` component from `react-bootstrap`.

[image]

AccordionItem.jsx

```
  <Accordion.Item eventKey="0">
    <Accordion.Header>Accordion Item #1</Accordion.Header>
    <Accordion.Body>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
      veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
      velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
      cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
      est laborum.
    </Accordion.Body>
  </Accordion.Item>
```

I want to test if the content show in the DOM after I click the expand arrow.
How should I write a test for it?

accordion-item.test.js

```
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import React from "react";

import AccordionItem from "./AccordionItem";

it("render AccordionItem Component", () => {
  let accordionItem = shallow(<AccordionItem />);
  // what's next???
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use [`find`](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/find.html) to get elements inside the accordion by [`displayName`](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/find.html#:%7E:text=Component%20Display%20Name%3A), like this:

```
it("App", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<App />);
  const firstItem = wrapper.find("AccordionHeader").at(0);
  expect(firstItem.text()).toBe("Accordion Item #1");
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/enzyme-react-bootstrap-mezxb?file=/src/App.test.js

You can also use css selectors (e.g. `.accordion-header`) but it's less recommended because your test will fail if bootstrap will change the elements' classes.

```
it("App", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<App />);
  const firstItem = wrapper.find(".accordion-header").at(0);
  expect(firstItem.text()).toBe("Accordion Item #1");
});
```